# Autocomplete="OFF" Not Working - Chrome Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, forms, google-chrome, autocomplete

I've been battling with this for for 2 years... need your help.

In mobile chrome, I cannot disable AUTOCOMPLETE ...

Chrome ignores

```
autocomplete="off"
```

This is on android, but I presume on iPhone also.

I have a simple contact form - no passwords or anything.

I absolutely need this to work, becasue on mobile, when chrome shows Autocomplete options, it breaksuser experience. How do I force Chrome mobile to not show it???

I've read like every question on this and nothing worked - I don't know what to do

Comment: Try `autocomplete=false`, as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29582380/4889889). You might also try the other answers to that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome keeps changing the way it handles autocomplete on each version, I solved this using jQuery, I make all the fields readonly and onclick/focus make it Not readonly. try this jQuery snippet:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//======fix for autocomplete
$('input, :input').attr('readonly',true);//readonly all inputs on page load, prevent autofilling on pageload

 $('input, :input').on( 'click focus', function(){ //on input click
 $('input, :input').attr('readonly',true);//make other fields readonly
 $( this ).attr('readonly',false);//but make this field Not readonly
 });
//======./fix for autocomplete
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form, you could try with adding autocomplete="off" to form as well.